# Adding a numerical field to each sent packet in the network layer and getting the most suitable function of the Inet to assign value to that field

Tags: omnet++, inet

If we want to add a numerical field to each sent packet in the network layer as trailer section, what changes should be made in the structure of the packets and the most suitable function from which the Inet file is suitable for attribution?